# how to manage nodejs instances selectively

Tags: node.js

we want to have ability to run demo server independently from testing env. For these purposes we use two nodejs instances run with different options(ports).

I am trying to implement two different CI jobs for managing these two servers independently but see no way to stop nodejs instances selectively.

Is there a way to make something like named instances to stop/start/restart them separately?

Or it is only way to use something like *forever* to watch file changes(want to avoid this because of time limit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forever.js to name each application you run

```
forever --uid app start app.js
forever --uid app1 start app.js
```

Then you can restart individual apps

```
forever restart app1
```